# overloading method user input

Tags: java, input, overloading

I am trying to use method overloading to find the area of a rectangle. Only thing is the values have to be entered by the user. But if it has to accepted from the user, shouldn't we know the datatype of his input? And if we do, then the purpose of overloading becomes useless, because I already know the datatype.

Can you guys help me out?

You can add onto this code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class mtdovrld
{
   void rect(int a,int b)
   {
      int result = a*b;
      System.out.println(result);
   }

   void rect(double a,double b)
   {
      double result = a*b;
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}

class rectarea
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
   {
      mtdovrld zo = new mtdovrld();

      Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please enter values:");

      // Here is the problem, how can I accept values from user where I do not have to specify datatype and will still be accepted by method?
      double a = input.nextDouble();
      double b = input.nextDouble();

      zo.rect(a,b);

   }
}
```

Comment: Side comment - Java conventions -> class names in CamelCase

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is make it so the input is a string.

so the user can input 9, or 9.0 or if you want to get crazy maybe nine.

then you would parse the string and cast it to an int or a double. then call either of the overloaded methods.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Convertstringtoint.htm

that shows you how to convert a string to an int

Answer (score 0):

You can overload with different type parameters for example String, or even some object. This would be a precaution in case the programmer using your rectangle method passed in the wrong parameter type, the method won't break.

Answer (score 0):

**Its better to handle the checking of the input in the program, rather than letting the user bother about it**.

Eg:

`1. First let the user give values as String.`

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   String val_1 = scan.nextLine();
   String val_2 = scan.nextLine();
```

`2. Now Check the type using this custom method. Place this method in the class mtdovrld,`
   `Call this method after taking user input, and from here call the rect() method.`

**Method to Validate:**

```
public void chkAndSet(String str1, String str2)
    {

       try{

             rect(Integer.parseInt(str1), Integer.parseInt(str2));


          }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex)
          {

             rect(Double.parseDouble(str1), Double.parseDouble(str2));

          }
    }
```